# Java nested loops to check if elements in an array match

Tags: java, arrays

Object class loop (`array1` and `array2` are the arrays):

```
public int howManyMatches(int[] array2){
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < array1.length; j++)
        {
            if (array2[i] == (array1[j]))
            {
                count++;   
            } 
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Main class checking:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ticketArray.length; i++)
{
    int count = ticketArray[i].howManyMatches(array2);

    if (count == 4) 
    {
        System.out.println("All 4 elements match");
    }

    else if (count == 3)
    {
        System.out.println("Match 3");
    }

    else
    {
        System.out.println("Arrays do not match.");
    }
}
```

Loop only returns the `else` statement, even if the arrays are all matching. `array1` is an input based array, and `array2` is hardcoded.

Comment: What is the value of `count`? (I suspect it's double the expected value. Can you figure out why?)

Comment: What is a "match" to you? As is, you are comparing each element of each array against each other. Example: [1,2,3] and [1,2,3] => 3 , but [2,2,3] and [2,2,4] => 4 Is that intended?

Comment: Does _position_ count for matches?  Should [1,2,3,4]  and [4,3,2,1] have four matches, or none?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a binary search

```
    private int[] array1;
    // Arrays.sort(array1); if array1 not chaning sort it once here
    public int howManyMatches(int[] array2) {
        int count = 0;
        Arrays.sort(array2);
        // Arrays.sort(array1); if array1 changing sort it here
        for (int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
            int index = Arrays.binarySearch(array1, array2[i]);
            if (index >= 0)
                count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
```